# Display only searched result in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'have a TextBox for searching in DataGrid , and the result only select the searched row in DataGrid , so I want the DataGrid to display only the selected row result and hide all other rows.

Here's my code   :

`

```
    private void SearchTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvUnit.Rows)
        {
            if(row.Cells["Id"].Value.ToString().ToLower().StartsWith(SearchTextBox.Text.ToLower()))
            {
                row.Selected = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

`

Comment: What's the source behind your datagridview? Just a tip: apply the filter to the source and display results.

Comment: are you using a datatable as a datasource?

Comment: @CarlsJr.  I'm using Datasource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manipulate row visibility (no matter if use `DataSource` or not)

```
private void SearchTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dgvUnit.CurrentCell = null;

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvUnit.Rows)
    {
        if(row.Cells["Id"].Value.ToString().ToLower().StartsWith(SearchTextBox.Text.ToLower()))
        {
            row.Visible = true;
            row.Selected = true;
        }
        else
        {
            row.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this but I get an exception "Row associated with the currency manager's position cannot be made invisible."

Comment: Forgot that you have to set `CurrentCell` to null before change visibility of row. Fixed and try again.